# caption spacing between figures

Tags: captions

I have been trying to put 2 figures next to each other, however i have noticed that the spacing between caption is non existing,

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.52\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figures/badtimes2.eps}
  \caption{Stock index, 2nd half, shaded areas highlight the bad time}
 \end{minipage}%
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.52\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figures/decr-sent.eps}
  \caption{Sentiment index. Shaded areas highlight the periods of increasing and decreasing sentiment.}
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

[image: spacing]

can someone help me fix this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: thank you so much guys, that worked magic!

Comment: Even better {dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}

Comment: Hi, John! could u be more specific of where exactly to put this command? thank you in advance

Comment: @FilipPierzgalski He suggest you uses `\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}` instead of `\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}` in the two `minipage` (and don't forget to use `\hfill` between the two `minipage` environments as suggested by *egreg*). This code create a gap of exactly one column sep between the two pictures (the same gap as in a default two-column document).

Comment: I have included a option with subfigure. It might be better to work with in some cases and might help with your question.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

sum of your minipage width is larger than text width (`0.52\textwidth` + `0.52\textwidth` = `1.04 \textwidth`. at least you need to reduce it to `1\textwidth` or as is sugested in comment below your question`reduce`minipage`  width to value smaller than 0.5. For example 0.48 can be good value.

beside use of `minipage` it my be worth to consider `tabularx` instead them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figures/badtimes2.eps}
  \caption{Stock index, 2nd half, shaded areas highlight the bad time}
 \end{minipage}\hfill
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figures/decr-sent.eps}
  \caption{Sentiment index. Shaded areas highlight the periods of increasing and decreasing sentiment.}
 \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}XX@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/badtimes2.eps}
  \caption{Stock index, 2nd half, shaded areas highlight the bad time}
 &
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/decr-sent.eps}
  \caption{Sentiment index. Shaded areas highlight the periods of increasing and decreasing sentiment.}
 \end{tabularx}
```

[image]

above image belong to your approach (with corrected `minipage` width), bottom image is result at use of `tabularx`. in test i use `article` document class, since you not provide any information about your document layout˙and used document class.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `subfigure`, with the package `subcaption`? Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Stock index, 2nd half, shaded areas highlight the bad time}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Sentiment index. Shaded areas highlight the periods of increasing and decreasing sentiment.}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have included a small space between the figures with `\hfill`, following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483921/115089). You can remove it if you prefer the figures closer to each other.

The output is this: [image]