# Fully justifying subfigures

Tags: floats, subfloats

In a figure environment, I can use `\centering` to achieve this effect:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth} A \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth} B \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth} C \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

And they would be stacked together like this in the output

```
-ABC-
```

Where `-` denotes space.

Instead of centering, could we `\justify`?, i.e.

```
A-B-C
```

Of course I can manually do it by inserting `\hspace{0.5\textwidth}` between A-B and B-C, but is there something more automatic available?

I tried `\justify` from `ragged2e` which didn't work, and neither did `\begin{justify}`. I assume these are for text and that's why they didn't work.

Comment: as always justification is the default so you almost never need `\justify`, but the last line of a paragraph (even with `\justify`) is allowed to be short, you could use `\end{subfigure}\hfill \begin{subfigure}` between the figures

Comment: The subfigures are acually left-justified by default (if you omit \centering) so that leaves space at the right. You're right about `\hfill` though, that did the trick. I didn't know I could use it multiple times on the same line. You could post it as an answer.

Comment: No.  As I say they are subject to the standard paragraph justification but you have a one line paragraph, it is exactly the same as if you have a `\parbox{\textwidth}{a b c}`  the paragagrah `a b c` is justified but as teh last line has `\parfillski` added and ther is only one line, it looks the same as left justified unless you set `\parfillskip` to 0pt or add `\hfill` between the letters. there is no difference between positioning subfigures and positioning letters, it is exactly the same code.

Comment: Oh wow. Yes, setting `\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}` works. What's the best place to put it? I've put it right after `begin{figure}`. I think it's a neater way and you should include it in your answer to make it more complete.

Comment: That only works if the subfigures are big enough that one word space between each figure is enough stretch to make them full width. adding `\hfill` is far more general as that is infinite stretch.

Answer (score 2):

As always, justification is the default so you almost never need `\justify`, but the last line of a paragraph (even with `\justify`) is allowed to be short, you could use

```
\end{subfigure}\hfill \begin{subfigure}
```

between the figures